# How do I find the maximum value between two variables in a vector?

Tags: r, max

I have a vector (`1:1000`) composed by random numbers and I need to find the maximum value within it.

This should be done by comparing the first value of the vector with the second and, if the second is less than the first, I need to discard it and continue onto the next one.

I should continue to iterate the process until there are no larger values left than the one I am currently scrutinising.

Comment: which language you want to use?

Comment: i need to compute this in software r

Comment: Maybe try: `x[ which.max(x) ]`

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output.

Comment: I need to create a loop, using for and if but i don't know how

Comment: x(4,90,5,7) i have to make a comparison between 4 and 90, and if, like in this case 4<90, i have to compare, 90 with 5, and in this case 90>5 so i have to compare 90 with 7 and so on

Comment: Do you have to use forloops?

Comment: yes! i need to use for loops

Comment: i tried your code but it doesn't work

Comment: i'll try to explain to you properly what i have to do.

Comment: I have a vector 1:1000 like this c(10.5, 5, 9, 6.5...7) i need to find the maximum values comparing element by element those numbers. Comparing the different numbers, i also need to discard a number when it is minor than the previosious and hold it if it is mayor. Then i'll have to iterate the procedure for all the element of the vector.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to perform ***found-and-hold***?

```
> x[seq_along(x) >= which.max(x)]
[1] 0.94467527 0.66079779 0.62911404 0.06178627
```

or just output the max value?

```
> max(x)
[1] 0.9446753
```

---

If you want to have `for` loop to perform found-and-hold, you can try the code below (follow OP's intended procedure)

```
p <- 1
for (i in 1:(length(x) - 1)) {
  for (j in i:length(x)) {
    if (x[i] < x[j]) p <- j
  }
  if (p > i) next
}
x[p:length(x)]
```

giving

```
> x[p:length(x)]
[1] 0.94467527 0.66079779 0.62911404 0.06178627
```

## Data

```
> set.seed(1)
> x <- runif(10)
> x
 [1] 0.26550866 0.37212390 0.57285336 0.90820779 0.20168193 0.89838968
 [7] 0.94467527 0.66079779 0.62911404 0.06178627
```

Comment: From comments, it looks like OP wants to create the max function, using forloops and if.

Comment: @zx8754 Okey, I just see OP's comments. I have added the `for` loop version right now.

Comment: I need to perform found-and-hold, with for and if, i'll try the code @zx8754 provide me

Answer (score 0):

With a loop you can use this solution:

```
n <- 1:1000
MAX = -Inf    
for (i in 1:length(n)) {
  if (x > MAX) MAX <- x
  }
```

For find a maximum is important set `"MAX = -Inf"`.